# How to use asciidoctorj-diagram with Java or Groovy?

Tags: groovy, asciidoctor, plantuml

PlantUML is a great extension for Asciidoc, but I can't figure out how to use from my groovy code.

As far as I can see, the `asciidoctorj-diaram` module should be part of the current `asciidoctorj`-Release, so I guess I need no additional dependency. But my code which renders asciidoc fine, does not render the PlantUML diagrams. It says:

```
invalid style for open block: plantuml
```

Any idea what could be wrong? The `asciidoctorj-diagram` examples I find on the net all use the gradle-plugin :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the library is part of the AsciidoctorJ project, there is a separate java library called: `asciidoctorj-diagram` (the java version of `asciidoctor-diagram`)

Are you sure that you have `asciidoctorj-diagram` on your classpath? Here the maven coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-diagram</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need to tell Asciidoctor that `asciidoctor-diagram` is required. See line `<1>` in the following plain java example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor asciidoctor =
             org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor.Factory.create();

    asciidoctor.requireLibrary("asciidoctor-diagram"); // <1>

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("== Diagrams\n");
    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("[plantuml,auth-protocol]\n");
    sb.append("....\n");
    sb.append("Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request\n");
    sb.append("Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response\n");
    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request\n");
    sb.append("Alice <-- Bob: another authentication Response\n");
    sb.append("....\n");

    String html = asciidoctor.convert(sb.toString(), 
             new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>());
    System.out.println(html);
}
```

---

By the way, there is also a maven example: [asciidoctor-diagram-example](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/asciidoctor-diagram-example). But this example requires the `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` which is similar to the gradle plugin.

Comment: thanx for the detailed answer. The dependency and `requireLibrary` where the missing ingredient... now I have to figure out why it doesn't find the GraphViz "dot" tool...

Comment: Btw: yes, graphviz is installed. I wonder why asciidocfx just works and I do have these problems...

Comment: If you do not want to add `dot` on you path; In the maven plugin, the path to `dot` can be specified with a config: `<graphvizdot>C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe</graphvizdot>`. You can have a look there to figure out how you can do the same in your java program.